# Django Submit Form Working Development Not Deployment

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a form that creates a new blog post and redirects me to that blog post. The form works properly in development but when I deployed the app to Heroku and click the submit button nothing happens. Is something wrong with the database, my form, or the admin functionality (which is required to access the form)? In terms of the database (in case it has anything to do with that) I put a .dump on Amazon S3 and pushed it to my Heroku Postgres database. Any help would be great!

## Relevant section from views.py:

```
@login_required 
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            if post.category == 'progresstracker':
                return redirect('books.views.pt_detail', slug=post.slug, category=post.category)
            elif post.category == 'resources':
                return redirect('books.views.resources')
            else:
                return redirect('books.views.bt_detail', slug=post.slug, category=post.category)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})  

def pt_detail(request, slug, category):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug, category__slug=category)
    template = CATEGORY_TEMPLATES.get(post.category.slug)
    return render(request, template, {'post': post})
```

## The form:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block nav %}
    <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/progresstracker">Progress Tracker</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="/blogtopics" class="dropbtn">Blog Topics</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="/blogtopics/computer-science">Computer Science</a>
            <a href="/blogtopics/data-science">Data Science</a>
            <a href="/blogtopics/other">Other</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/resources">Resources</a></li>
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<div id="content">
    <div class="padding">
        <h1>New post</h1>
            <form method="POST" class="progresstracker-form">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>

            </form>

    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you sure that there should be no `action` attribute in your form? This usually determines where to post it to in this case.

Comment: Code looks okay. Are you sure you have created the tables in your database. Also could you define "nothing happens"? Does the page reload for example?

Comment: How do I ensure I've created the tables in my database? The page doesn't reload or redirect. I click it and everything stays the same as was it was before I clicked it.

Comment: Can you make sure that the ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] in the settings.py? without ALLOWED_HOSTS it may work on development but not in production. And unless you are not posting to the same url, you should have action in your form HTML element. Also It would be useful if you post the error log from Heroku

Comment: It is indeed set to ['*']. So I think it has something to do with the fact that when I have DEBUG = True the website works fine but I get the above issue, but when I have DEBUG = False, I get a "could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?" error. I've been troubleshooting it for hours and can't figure it out.

Comment: Am I okay setting action="" ie blank? As you can see in the view, the form data and redirect should be sent to different url's depending on the value of form Category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual issue is the migrations, If you will take a look inside the heroku logs you will see a `relation` error for your model.

To solve this issue:

1. First make sure you have added all the migrations to the git
   repo:

   `git add <myapp>/migrations/*
        git commit -m "Fix Heroku deployment"
        git push heroku`
2. Then you need to migrate once again on Heroku by running these
   commands:

heroku run bash

```
~$  ./manage.py makemigrations
~$  ./manage.py migrate
~$  exit
```